# Триггер, почему не работает ? SQL,Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер, триггеры-sql

Создал триггер,чтобы ограничить ввод данных в мое поле. Если будет введены значения меньше нуля или больше 100,то должен сработать триггер и выдать исключения. Однако он всегда выдает исключения, даже когда число в районе от 0 до 100. Подскажи как мне сделать,чтобы он работал коректнно.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_mark() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$        
BEGIN
IF (mark <0 OR mark>100)    
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'число вне границы';
END IF;  
END;  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER ch_check_mark
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON markk 
FOR Statement EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_mark();
```

Comment: А чем вам констрейнт обычный не угодил?

Comment: Хочу поработать с триггером и узнать, как им пользоваться,чтобы в дальнейшем использовать.

Comment: Тут, задал вроде бы условия,а оно не хочет правильно работать.

Comment: Решил вопрос,всем спасибо

Comment: Если Вы решили вопрос, то приведите, пожалуйста, решение в виде ответа на собственный вопрос. Или удалите вопрос.